# Consulta SQL, filtrar y ordenar por fechas/hora con tolerancia de +- 2minutos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas, orderby

tengo una serie de registros en sql en la que se escriben registros conforme se suciten eventos
las columnas son:

sitios,
enlace,
enlace secundario,
asl,
fechayhora,
estatus

[image: concentrado generado]

necesito agrupar los datos segun su fecha/hora con una tolerancia de +- 3 minutos, ejemplo

[image: rsultado de filtro]

Por ahora los agrupo por ASL, pero tengo casos en los cuales difiere el dato y estan dentro del rango de hora y fecha.

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de la tabla? Qué DBMS usas? Actualiza tu respuesta con esta info, por favor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que tal julio, utilizo sql,actualmente los agrupo por asl, pero tengo casos en los cuales tengo sitios  con diferente asl que tubieron un evento(down)

Comment: sql es un lenguaje... no es un motor de base de datos, y cada base de datos tiene particularidades... que motor usas? vos lo vas a hacer con un query o con un procedimiento? como vas a medir los +-2 si hay mas ventanas que se incluyan? o sea, si alguien esta en 2, otro en 4, otro en 6, y otro en 8, como lo vas a agrupar??? lo que queres hacer requiere mas reglas....

Comment: genero un query con la libreria de oledb en vb, la informacion la obtengo de un reporte en excel